# Integration of Junit4 with Jmeter

Tags: java, junit, webdriver, jmeter

A test suite has been developed using WebDriver and JUnit4. Its working fine, but now we need to integrate test suite with Jmeter for load testing. The problem is that the classes use the Annotation of `"@RunsWith"` to test a test case with multiple inputs and JMeter does not support this annotation.

> Is there any workaround available ? (I could not find any, but may be some one has tried something)
>
> Is this really a good approach, to first write test cases using web driver

Comment: What is your problem exactly with JMeter. JMeter runs your unit-test as JUnit 3.x? What class runner JMeter is run?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, you just has old version of JMeter that works only with JUnit 3.x. In such a case you have only 2 choses: rewerite your JUnit in 3.x style or upgrade JMeter.